# This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server to communicate with SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc

fijense que tengo un problema, estoy trabajando una aplicacion con php en mvc en un servidor linux, configure las extensiones de php en el Cpanel, en ese sentido, un cliente tiene una base de datos en sql server en un servidor windows, entonces lo que hice fue instalar la extension de pdo_sqlsrv en el servidor linux y en el servidor windows instale el ODBC, siguiendo la documentacion que tiene microsoft, pero aun asi no quiere conectar, me sigue mostrando el mensaje de error que necesita el ODBC Driver: este es el mensaje:
Error connecting to SQL Server: SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server to communicate with SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver for SQL Server for x64: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712. No se si alguien tiene una idea de que me puede estar faltando, se los agradeceria mucho. La version de PHP en el server es 7.3.20 y la version de SQL SERVER es la 2019, instale el ODBC 17.
[image: Versiones de ODBC instalados en SQL Server]

Comment: El error parece indicar que no tienes el driver adecuado instalado (`x64`). Ejecuta `phpinfo()` y verifica si lo tienes instalado.

Comment: desde cpanel agregue la extension pdo_sqlsrv para que reconozca los comandos PDO con SQL Server, no se si a eos te refieres?